# Curl Redirect Issue

Tags: php, redirect, curl

0I'm trying to redirect the user to a 'Thank You' page on success, I'm using a simple php redirect.

```
header('Location: http://client.com/thank-you-one.php');
```

and I've added it into the snippet below but the redirect still isn't working, if anyone know why or can see where I'm going wrong I'd love some feedback.

```
$username = '*****';
    $password = '*****';


    //POPULATE THESE (and other fields) WITH REQUEST DATA
    $first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
    $last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['emailaddress'];
    $company_name = $_POST['companyname'];
    $date_of_birth = (''.$_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day'].'');
    $loyalty_number = $_POST['membernumber'];

    $host = 'http://api.client.com/users';
    $user_curl = curl_init($host);
    curl_setopt($user_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/vnd.aardvark.crm+json; version=1.3'));
    curl_setopt($user_curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
    curl_setopt($user_curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($user_curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($user_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('forename' = > $first_name, 'surname' = > $last_name, 'email' = > $email, 'company_name' = > $company_name, 'date_of_birth' = > $date_of_birth, 'loyalty_number' = > $loyalty_number)));
    curl_setopt($user_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $return = curl_exec($user_curl);

    $info = curl_getinfo($user_curl);
    if ($info['http_code'] == '200') {
        $data = json_decode($return, true);

        $tag_curl = curl_init($host.'/'.$data['id'].'/tags/'.$_POST['favorite'].'');
        curl_setopt($tag_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/vnd.aardvark.crm+json; version=1.3'));
        curl_setopt($tag_curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
        curl_setopt($tag_curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($tag_curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($tag_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $tag_return = curl_exec($tag_curl);


        $ml_curl = curl_init($host.'/'.$data['id'].'/mailinglists/3');
        curl_setopt($ml_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/vnd.aardvark.crm+json; version=1.3'));
        curl_setopt($ml_curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
        curl_setopt($ml_curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ml_curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
        curl_setopt($ml_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $tag_return = curl_exec($ml_curl);



        header('Location: http://client.com/thank-you-one.php');
        echo 'test1';
    exit;

    } else {
        //analyse resonse with 
        $data = json_decode($return, true);
        print_r($data);
        echo 'test2';
    }


    curl_close($user_curl);
    curl_close($tag_curl);
    curl_close($ml_curl);
```

Comment: *sidenote:* remember to call `exit;` after `header('Location: $url');`

Comment: what is working, what are you getting instead of the redirect. is it the json output?

Comment: shound't this be `200`  if ($info['http_code'] == '201') {

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I've added your examples but the redirect still isn't working. I've logged into the api panel and I can see the data been sent to the correct location but they is still no redirect.

Comment: sidenote won't solve your problem. just a code recommendation.

Comment: @AdamWadsworth: add an echo statement in the `if` and `else` blocks and see which one's getting executed.

Comment: @AmalMurali I added echo "testing"; after the redirect and nothing showed up ??? is they any reason to this ?

Comment: @AdamWadsworth: add different `echo` statements in both the blocks and identify which block is getting executed.

Comment: @AmalMurali I've added echo 'test'; in both areas and nothing has been displated?

Comment: @AmalMurali Sorry the live verion has got different statments, Have you got any suggestions. I have like an hour to fix this before i piss my client off. Any other suggestions would be really apprecated.

Comment: @AmalMurali the echo is now working. Its picking up the echo statment directly after the php header redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is your testing for `http_code` `201`. change it to `200`

`if ($info['http_code'] == '200')` {